# Inserting a datatable into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datatable

I currently have a populated datatable, but I'm having trouble inserting it into my existing (empty) database.

I have looked into sqlbulkcopy as well, but haven't had much luck.

Although using Entity Framework I would expect:

```
_db.TableName.AddRange(dt);
```

To properly insert the new data from my datatable.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: You would not normally work with a `DataTable` and Entity Framework at the same time.

Comment: @techspider cannot convert System.Data.Datatable to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<tableName.tableName>

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What would be the preferred way of inserting data into SQL Server via a Datatable then?  (if not EF?)

Comment: If you're using data table, then you can just use raw ADO.NET and skip EF. EF is an Object Relational Mapping framework, and DataTable is not an object. They don't generally mix.

Comment: Using a data table is fine, but combining data tables and Entity frameowork is odd.

Comment: Are you doing _db.SaveChanges(), because only adding items into the list wont do the work, you will have to save the db object in order to insert data into the database.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I gathered that from your first comment - can you suggest a different means of inserting?

Comment: SqlBulkCopy, but you did not include the code of what you tried so we can't really help you with what you did wrong when you tried it.

Comment: If you really want to use EF, then stop using DataTable. Instead, create a Model object to represent your data, then you can add a collection of them to your context and then save those. For example, `List<Customer>` instead of `DataTable` would be how you pass the data around.

Comment: Google `TableAdapter`.

Comment: Just want to reiterate the comment by @mason which was the most succinct explanation of EF. Learning EF takes some getting used to, especially when moving away from previous methods of data interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few steps. First you need to create the table on the database, this is generally done not at run time for lots of complex reasons. Research Entity Framework Code First for more details on how to do this.

Secondly if you truly want to use Entity Framework you will need to convert your data table into a set of objects of the correct type.

Honestly though I would avoid Entity Framework and embed a `CREATE TABLE` script (or even better define it before you execute) and then use SqlBulkCopy, just note that SqlBulkCopy needs the table defined ahead of time.

Comment: What would the point of a CREATE TABLE script be if I had(and have) already created the database/table structure in MSSQL Server?

Comment: @confusedandamused: You said empty database and didn't mention the table being created.

Comment: I misspoke - by empty I meant the database existed as well as the table structure (columns) have been defined and match the data table.

Comment: @confusedandamused if you have the time, and the refactor isn't too large/crazy, you should refactor away from datatables/datasets and into code first `EF`. However, If you use datatables, I found it useful to sync it to the database table with a `TableAdapter`. I've never used SqlBulkCopy so that may be a better solution.